Calculating downrange and crossrange distance and velocity relative to a surface point
I've started to go about implementing a descent guidance algorithm I found in a 1997 paper by D'Souza. However, I've hit a snag. The coordinate system is in terms of downrange position ($x$, relative to the target), crossrange position ($y$, relative to the target), and target-relative altitude ($z$). Altitude is not a problem, but I am unsure how to calculate downrange position and crossrange position relative to a target on the surface. Likely spherical trigonometry is needed, but I do not have enough knowledge to know where to start. Additionally, the algorithm also requires velocity in $u,v,w$ coordinate space (the derivatives of $x,y,z$ respectively).
I am working in a simulation, so it's okay to assume some things such as the ability to have perfect state vectors. Additionally, I have perfect knowledge of the Moon-centered inertial position vector of the target point and its latitude and longitude.
Thanks for any help, I greatly appreciate it!

I've only glanced at the D'Souza paper, but my understanding is that the dynamics there are all Cartesian, so you're trying to move from knowing where you are above a sphere to that.  I'm going to try to be generic in my formulation here so do let me know if I've missed something vital.
Let's assume you're starting with:

a sphere-centered vehicle position $\vec{r}$ which is initially $\vec{r}_0$
a sphere-centered position of a target on a spherical surface $\vec{L}$ (for Landing zone)

The plane that includes both the vehicle and the target is defined by its normal vector $\vec{n} = (\vec{r}_0 \times \vec{L}) / (|r_0||L|)  $ (using the vector cross-product).  The downrange direction is in that plane.  Crossrange is out-of-plane.
To compute downrange distance at any point, you can find the in-plane component of the position vector by subtracting out the out-of-plane component
$$
\vec{r}_\text{in-plane} = \vec{r} - \vec{n}(\vec{n} \cdot \vec{r})
$$
then using the definition of the dot product to find the angle subtended between the vehicle and the target, and then multiplying that by the radius (presumably the magnitude of $\vec{L}$) to find the downrange distance $x$
$$
\vec{r_\text{in-plane}} \cdot \vec {L} = |r_\text{in-plane}||L|\cos{\theta}
$$
$$
\theta = \cos^{-1}(\vec{r_\text{in-plane}} \cdot \vec {L})/(|r_\text{in-plane}||L|)
$$
$$
x = \text{radius}*\theta = |L|*\theta
$$
The crossrange $y$ should correspond to $\vec{n} \cdot \vec{r}$ if it's sufficiently small. Otherwise, you might find the subtended angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}_\text{in-plane}$ and multiply that by the radius of the body to get a distance along the surface, as above.
As RyanC points out in the comments, the downrange and crossrange directions can be defined more generally and arbitrarily--you can create the plane by instead cross-multiplying the target position $\vec{L}$ and any preferred downrange-ish direction $\vec{d}_\text{ish}$ and recover an actually-downrange (i.e. perpendicular to $\vec{L}$ / tangent to the sphere) direction $\vec{d}$ in two cross-multiplications (this is also how horizontal is defined when defining an LVLH frame from position and velocity vectors):
$$
\vec{n} = \vec{L} \times \vec{d}_\text{ish}
$$
$$
\vec{d} = \vec{n} \times \vec{L}
$$
That doesn't make a difference to the above except that (again as pointed out) cross-range need not start at zero, as it does if we start only with our position and the target position; either way, the core parts are: the definition of the plane cutting the sphere; the plane's intersection with the surface is aligned with the +/- downrange directions; and the direction normal to the plane is the crossrange direction. Everything else can be derived from those ideas and vector math.

I am unsure what you mean by $\vec{r}_\text{in-plane} = \vec{r} - \vec{n} \cdot \vec{r}$; $\vec{n} \cdot \vec{r}$ would be a scalar, no?

@ThePuzzlemaker good catch. I was trying to get the projection of $\vec{r}$ along $\vec{n}$ to remove that component from $\vec{r}$, leaving only the in-plane components.  I believe I have to multiply the dot product by $\vec{n}$ (which I defined as a unit vector) to get the full out-of-plane vector I'm interested in.  Correcting that now.

What about downrange and crossrange velocity? How can those be calculated? Also, how can the sign of crossrange and downrange position be determined? (negative downrange is west in a direct orbit, negative crossrange is south in a direct orbit, or any other combination as long as it's consistent)

@ErinAnne There are other possible coordinate definitions. The cross-range you chose assumes the lander begins at y=0, already headed in the right direction, which is not what D'Souza assumed, in the equations on 1377 and the graphs on 1380. Another way to do it, the natural choice for landing an aircraft on a runway, is to define the y=0 surface as any arbitrary plane containing the entire L vector. Name the surface for the compass bearing or azimuth of the tangent vector at L to the chosen great circle passing through it, as is done for airport runways.

@ThePuzzlemaker Velocity uses the same operations as position: compute projections of the full velocity vector onto component directions via the dot product with unit vectors along the axes. The problem assumes that the starting velocity can be in any direction at any speed. Part of your solution needs to be calculating the changes to it necessary to arrive at the target anyway.

@RyanC hmm. Is what I've written still useful, you think, or does it need to hew closer to d'Souza's choices?  Your runway analogy seems like the next-most-obvious way to define "downrange" by using an intended landing direction

@ErinAnne  it's definitely useful: the vector dot and cross products are the core idea.  I'd just redefine the downrange direction to make it slightly more general.
